# Match by char length in a SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a SELECT statement. I'm wondering if it's possible to match by char length in a SELECT statement? So, for example. If a word has a character length of 3 or less, and if it matches that word, it would count as 1 match. If a word has a character length of over 3, and if it matches that word, it will count as 2 matches. Is that possible?

```
SELECT colName, 
( colName LIKE  '% 22 %' ) + 
( colName LIKE  '% 333 %' ) + 
( colName LIKE  '% 4444 %' ) as matches
FROM tableName
HAVING matches > 0 
AND matches = (select max(
( colName LIKE  '% 22 %' ) + 
( colName LIKE  '% 333 %' ) + 
( colName LIKE  '% 4444 %' )
) from tableName) limit 30
```

EXAMPLE:

```
22 = 1 match
333 = 1 match
4444 = 2 matches
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `IF` or `CASE`

```
SELECT colName,
    (colName LIKE '% 22 %') +
    (colName LIKE '% 333 %') +
    IF(colName LIKE '% 4444 %', 2, 0) AS matches
```

You could also use multiplication:

```
SELECT colName,
    (colName LIKE '% 22 %') +
    (colName LIKE '% 333 %') +
    2 * (colName LIKE '% 4444 %') AS matches
```